# SqlQuery EntityKey and return corresponding object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entitykey

I would like to query my database based on a EntityKey is there a inbuild (or easier approach) to do this?

My current approach, would be something like this:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    context.DataBase.SqlQuery<TestTable>("select * from @p0 where @p1 = @p2", EntityKey.EntitySetName, EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Name, EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value);
}
```

(This solution currently has the problem, that the EntitySetName isnt the TableName and I would need to grab the TableName out of the MetaData, same with the Name of the Id which could also be different than database)

Or is there even a way to do this with LINQ? (which I would prefer, since I wouldnt need to manually translate)

Comment: Ur Q is not very clear..What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rupesh: I am getting absolute no error, I just want to know if there is a way to query the Database with the help of the EntityKey property, the link you have posted in your answer is no use for me since I am already using EntityFramework. My problem is just HOW can achieve this, with ONLY the EntityKey.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `context.Set<TestTable>().Find(EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value)`?

Comment: @SteveRuble Not really, thats why I am asking HOW to achieve it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type of the entity you're retrieving, you can use the `Set` method on DbContext to get a `DbSet`, and the `Find` method on `DbSet` to get an entity by its key(s).

```
var dbSet = dbContext.Set<TestTable>();
var entity = dbSet.Find(EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value);
```

The `Find` method knows how to turn use the key value to get an entity; in fact, the signature is `Find(params object[])` so you can pass in multiple key values if your table has a composite key (as long as they're in the right order).

Comment: gave you the +50 since this solution doesnt require to cast to IObjectContextAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your `DbContext` to the `IObjectContextAdapter` interface and from there you can access the underlying `ObjectContext` object which has the [`GetObjectByKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjectbykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
    var entity = objectContext.GetObjectByKey(yourEntityKey);
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this only works for the ones already loaded and related to this context and doesnt query the database.

Comment: No, according to the msdn it should query the db: "If the object is currently not loaded into the object context, a query is executed in an attempt to return the object from the data source."